# Is it possible factor out $(x - b)$ from $(x^n-b^n)$ when $n$ is a fraction?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

[Factoring out $(x-b)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqEwd.png)

But how to factor out $(x-1)$ when the polynomial has the power of a negative integer where $n=-4$

$x^{-4}-1$

And even worst how to perform the factorization when the polynomial is to the power of an fraction? $n=-4/7$

$x^{-4/7}-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example :

You could call $x^{-1/7}=\frac{1}{x^{1/7}}=y$

So
$$y^4-1=(y-1)(y+1)(y^2+1)=\left(\frac{1}{x^{1/7}}-1\right)(y^3+y^2+y+1)$$
$$=-\frac{1}{x^{1/7}}\left(x^{1/7}-1\right)(y^3+y^2+y+1)$$

Comment: But you only factored out (y-1) and need to factor out (x-1).

Comment: Just a side note, how to type x^(1-n) in a maths format?

Comment: You can only factor out $x^{1/7}-1$ at best

Comment: You can actually write
$$x^{1/7}-1=(x-1)\frac{x^{1/7}-1}{x-1}=(x-1)\frac{y^6-y^7}{1-y^7}=
(x-1)\frac{y^6}{1+y+y^2+y^3+y^4+y^5+y^6}$$ where that rational factor is a differentiable function of $y$ around, for example the point $y=1$. This may be sufficient for some purposes of "factoring".

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question: $x^{-n}-1$ can be rewritten as $(-1/x^n)*(x^n-1)$, so you just factor $x-1$ out of the $x^n-1$ and leave the $-1/x^n$ on.

$$x^{-4}-1=(-1/x^4)*(x^4-1)$$

$$(-1/x^4)*(x^4-1)=((-1/x^4)*(x^2+1)*(x+1))*(x-1)$$